# UITableViewCellReorderControl color on clear background

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with transparent background and I also made `UITableViewCell`s background transparent. I have `UITableViewCellReorderControl` on the cells as I support reordering of cells.

It is ok in black background but when I set the holder view controller's background to white, I need UITableViewCellReorderControl to draw in a dark color.

It can't be just me and It shouldn't require iterating through lots of subviews (as seen on similar questions on stackoverflow.)

I do not need to customize the `UITableViewCellReorderControl` itself; I don't want to change the image.

Is there anything to do this other than iterating views to replace the image with a custom one?

Comment: Check this link http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/ Guess this helps